# Populating ListBox/View with just one item

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, wpf-controls

I have a `ListBox` (or `ListView`) I would like to populate, but my list only ever contains 1 item like this: (It is derived from my `Job` Class)

[image]

So the `ListBox` would have two columns, effectively 1 for the key, and 1 for the value, and then a row with each Key/Value pair.

I cant seem to work out how to do this with a collection of just 1 item, rather than many items.

EDIT:
I already have my Job Class, which has been auto generated from Linq. Partial Exmaple code:

```
public partial class Job : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
 private int _Id;

 private string _Hostname;

 [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Id", DbType="Int NOT NULL", IsPrimaryKey=true)]
    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Id;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Id != value))
            {
                this.OnIdChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._Id = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("Id");
                this.OnIdChanged();
            }
        }
    }

     [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Hostname", DbType="NVarChar(50)")]
    public string Hostname
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Hostname;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Hostname != value))
            {
                this.OnHostnameChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._Hostname = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("Hostname");
                this.OnHostnameChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use a collection at all then?

Comment: Hi, I already have my Job Class (edited question), and it already has the data inside it, as per the screenshot. But I just need to display this data in a neat form, so thought i'd use a listbox/listview – Maybe im on the wrong track here?

Comment: You just need to declare a `DataTemplate` to define what your data should look like. Follow the link in my answer to find out more.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I totally understand your question, but let's see if this answer can help you. So, when we display a collection of items in a `ListBox` or similar, we normally declare a [`DataTemplate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) to define how we want our data items to be rendered. We'd then apply that `DataTemplate` to the `ListBox.ItemTemplate` property.

However, when we just want to display a single item, there's simply no point in using a data collection and an `ItemsControl` of some sort. Instead, we can use the same `DataTemplate`, but just apply it to a single `ContentControl` instead. So a `ListBox` is used for multiple items and a `ContentControl` is used to render individual items. Try this:

In `Resources`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="YourDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type YourPrefix:YourDataType}">
    <!-- Define how you want your object to be rendered here -->
    <!-- You can use a Grid or StackPanel to layout your item here -->
</DataTemplate>
```

Then in XAML:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding YourSingleItemProperty}" 
    ContentTemplate="{StaticResource YourDataTemplate}" />
```

Comment: Hi, I already have my Job Class (edited question), and it already has the data inside it, as per the screenshot. But I just need to display this data in a neat form, so thought i'd use a listbox/listview – Maybe im on the wrong track here?

Answer (score 1):

Binding list of items to `ListView` is pretty straightforward and easy to do. This is just an example, but it should give basic idea on how to display exactly the values that you want.

If you have defined `ListView` in XAML like this:

```
<ListView Name="listViewJobs">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
           <GridViewColumn Header="Key" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=JobKey}" />
           <GridViewColumn Header="Value" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=JobValue}" />
       </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

And class `Job` that has the properties that you are binding the `ListView` columns to (in this case `JobKey` and `JobValue` properties):

```
public class Job
{
    private string jobKey;
    private string jobValue;

    // Key property that will be displayed 
    public string JobKey
    {
        get { return jobKey; }
        set { jobKey = value; }
    }

    // Value property that will be displayed
    public string JobValue
    {
        get { return jobValue; }
        set { jobValue = value; }
    }

    public Job(string jobKey, string jobValue)
    {
        this.jobKey = jobKey;
        this.jobValue = jobValue;
    }
}
```

To display list of `Jobs` in `ListView` all you need to do is this:

```
// Create the new list
List<Job> listJob = new List<Job>();
// Create new Job and add it to the list
Job newJob = new Job("exampleKey", "exampleValue");
listJob.Add(newJob);

// Set the list as the source for our ListView
listViewJobs.ItemsSource = listJob;
```

Binding will take care of linking columns to the properties from class and display the selected values from all the items that you add to the source list.

Comment: Hi, I already have my Job Class (edited question), and it already has the data inside it, as per the screenshot. But I just need to display this data in a neat form, so thought i'd use a listbox/listview

Comment: Well then you should be able to just bind the `ListView` columns to the existing properties of that `Job` class. As I said, this is just an example since you didn't post all the code, but it should be enough to help you achieve what you need.